# How to declare and fill an empty array

Tags: python, numpy

I got an error using numpy.zeros, it seems like my value a can't be filled since i got an error:

```
track=2
a=np.zeros(shape=(3,2))
eps_real=a(Cp-0.5,2)/2*3.14*track
eps_imag=a(Cp-0.5,2*track)/2*3.14*track
tau=a(Cp-1,2)
print tau
```

My error when i ran is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 35, in <module>
    eps_real=a(Cp-0.5,2)/2*3.14*track
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with the round brackets after the array? python thinks you are trying to call a. if you want to index it you need square brackets! eps_real=a[Cp-0.5,2]/2*3.14*track

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collection members in Python use square brackets (`[]`), not parentheses. So your code should be:

```
eps_real=a[Cp-0.5,2]/2*3.14*track
eps_imag=a[Cp-0.5,2*track]/2*3.14*track
tau=a[Cp-1,2]
```

Parentheses are used for calling functions, hence the error message `object is not callable`